# How do I make Cloudfiles FormPost return the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header to enable CORS?

Tags: python, ajax, rackspace-cloud, cloudfiles, pyrax

I want to enable CORS in my Rackspace CluodFiles container, so after reading the docs, I see I have to set some container metadata (I'm using Python and [Pyrax](https://github.com/rackspace/pyrax/)):

```
from pyrax import cloudfiles

cloudfiles.set_container_metadata(container_name, {
    'X-Container-Meta-Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'localhost:8000',
    'X-Container-Meta-Access-Control-Expose-Headers': 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin',
    'X-Container-Meta-Access-Control-Max-Age': '10',
})
print cloudfiles.get_container_metadata(container_name)
```

And I get as output:

```
{'x-container-meta-access-control-allow-origin': 'localhost:8000',
 'x-container-meta-access-control-expose-headers': 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin',
 'x-container-meta-access-control-max-age': '10',
 'x-container-meta-access-log-delivery': 'false'}
```

But the browser is not getting a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in the `OPTIONS` preflight request, so it cancels the AJAX call:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Content-Length: 131
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Allow: HEAD, GET, PUT, POST, COPY, OPTIONS, DELETE
X-Trans-Id: txXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Date: Wed, 13 Nov 2013 20:07:34 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
```

What's missing?

Thanks!

Comment: OP - What are you using on the browser side to handle the file uploads.

Comment: @ChrisRasco Sorry, it was a typo, I'm using `localhost:8000` as the Allow Origin value; I also tried with `example.com`; but the issue is not an incorrect header value, is just no header at all. I'm going to test the example page now. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rackspace has docs on how to enable CORS for a container [here](http://docs.rackspace.com/files/api/v1/cf-devguide/content/CORS_Container_Header-d1e1300.html). Example 7.11 is a CORS Test Page that'll let you test your configuration outside of attempting file uploads.

Test CORS Page - accepts a token and a URL to an object or container and let's you try calling an HTTP method on it.

***NOTE**: I've removed the "DELETE" method as that can have undesired results (Such as deleting your container/object)*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test CORS</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    Token<br><input id="token" type="text" size="64"><br><br>

    Method<br>
    <select id="method">
        <option value="GET">GET</option>
        <option value="HEAD">HEAD</option>
        <option value="POST">POST</option>
        <option value="PUT">PUT</option>
    </select><br><br>

    URL (Container or Object)<br><input id="url" size="64" type="text"><br><br>

    <input id="submit" type="button" value="Submit" onclick="submit(); return false;">

    <pre id="response_headers"></pre>
    <p>
    <hr>
    <pre id="response_body"></pre>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      function submit() {
          var token = document.getElementById('token').value;
          var method = document.getElementById('method').value;
          var url = document.getElementById('url').value;

          document.getElementById('response_headers').textContent = null;
          document.getElementById('response_body').textContent = null;

          var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

          request.onreadystatechange = function (oEvent) {
              if (request.readyState == 4) {
                  responseHeaders = 'Status: ' + request.status;
                  responseHeaders = responseHeaders + '\nStatus Text: ' + request.statusText;
                  responseHeaders = responseHeaders + '\n\n' + request.getAllResponseHeaders();
                  document.getElementById('response_headers').textContent = responseHeaders;
                  document.getElementById('response_body').textContent = request.responseText;
              }
          }

          request.open(method, url);
          request.setRequestHeader('X-Auth-Token', token);
          request.send(null);
      }
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

To set these values outside of pyrax or any other SDK, I've used the following code:

https://gist.github.com/chrisrasco/7455804

Remember to set your username, apikey, and path to your container in the appropriate places.

Comment: Actually, my error is that I'm setting an origin value of just a domain name and (optionally) a port number. But browsers also send the scheme (`http://` or `https://`) along with the domain, so the `X-Container-Meta-Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header set on the container must also begin with the scheme (`http://` or `https://`) depending on your server setup. Thanks @ChrisRasco for pointing me in the right direction!